# How can I know the callback is invoked for the last time?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, callback

According to [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)
When I pass a function to `String.replace()`, the function will be invoked multiple times, if the regular expression is global.

How can I pass a callback to this callback to know when all invocations are done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a callback. `String.prototype.replace` is a synchronous operation, therefore the code executes sequentially.

```
var s = 'test_test_test';

s = s.replace(/test/g, function () { return ''; });

console.log('replace done: ' + s);
```